# GCC: when can I expect returning large C++ objects to be efficient?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, g++

This questions is about C++98/C++03 rather than C++11, and is specific to the latest GCC (4.8) with the optimization turned on (*e.g.* `-O3`)

If I'm working with large objects, *e.g.*

```
struct point {
  float x, y;
};

typedef vector<point> points;

struct two {
  points a, b;
};
```

when can I expect GCC to optimize the `return`s of such objects from a function or method, such as

```
vector<two> large;
//...
return large;
```

Comment: It is worth bearing in mind that the answer could well depend on the exact version of `g++`.

Comment: ...and of course on the optimization options given to the compiler.

Comment: when RVO and NRVO is applicable. just check it on wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: When RVO and NRVO is applicable *and* your compiler implements it.

Comment: @pepper_chico the wiki article doesn't say anything about GCC, and the linked GCC 2.* doc (likely outdated) only seems to mention how to prevent the optimization

Comment: AFAICT the GCC folks treat cases in which (N)RVO fails as non-critical bugs. But don't expect them to continue optimizing for C++03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Pepper_chico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1000282/pepper-chico) commented, it is related to [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (RVO).

However, you could also consider the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification for your particular implementation. The [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (and [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)) specifies that on some occasions, a pair of registers can be used to return a small structure (instead of passing it on the stack)

BTW you could look at the generated assembly (using `g++ -fverbose-asm -S -O3`) or at intermediate gimple representations (dumping a lot of files with them using `g++ -fdump-tree-all -O3`, or using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) ....).

Some "large" objects are actually implemented as pointers (fitting in a register). For instance instances of `std::string` (on Linux, with libstdc++ from GCC 4.7 or 4.8, `sizeof(std::string) == sizeof(void*)`), even if the underlying string has millions of bytes. Likewise, `sizeof(std::vector<point>)` is often `3*sizeof(void*)` even for vectors of millions of `point`-s ...

Comment: As my question says, I'm talking about large objects (think megabytes). I don't understand what the size of the registers has to do with this.

Comment: *even for vectors of millions of point* and the point of RVO is whether those millions would be copied, not what happens to the 16 bytes

Answer (score 1):

You can always expect efficiency when you have guaranteed it, e.g. by moving.

Otherwise it's a good to assume efficiency until the contrary has been proved by measuring.

g++ 4.8 implements most C++11 features including move semantics, and `std::vector` does have move constructor (i.e., you're not dependent on RVO).

Comment: The OP was asking about C++98/03

Comment: @mockinterface: oh i didn't see that (makes no sense). does g++ 4.8 even *support* `-std=c++98`? it would have to carry two different standard library implementations then.

Comment: `-std=c++11` is not even the default in 4.8

Comment: @MaxB: The default standard depends on the distribution, e.g. it's C++11 with the Nuwen distro.  That wasn't what I asked. Anyway I checked it out with `-std=c++98`, and apparently it does behave as if it had at least two versions of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The well known rule of thumb for returning objects in C++98/03 is that you'll get most out of GCC if your objects can fit into your CPU register(s). Return such objects by value, return objects larger than this by a reference or a pointer.

With the C++11 standard there is more freedom for the compiler to move objects and of course for you to move them explicitly. With C++11 I'd start by returning everything you can by value and measure the hotpath coupled with inspecting the generated assembly to decide if switching to returning by references is worthwhile. A classic read on this is [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: *return objects larger than this by a reference or a pointer - and then count on the compiler to be smart and implement the copy elision for you*  Why would there even be any copying when you just return a pointer?

Comment: ... in any case, my question is about returning by value, and when it's efficient in GCC/C++98

Comment: Bad wording, fixed. Re your last comment, there is no mention of "by value" in the question. In any case the obvious answer is measuring your code, because your code is unique as the applied optimisations. Combinations of optimisation flags, applicable vectorization, etc etc, all have an effect. But if you want a general rule of thumb, return by value only when objects fit into registers.